# Autohotkey hold and release

Tags: autohotkey

I am trying to make a script that when you hold the side mouse button it will keep pressing `U`, and when I let go of the side button it will stop pressing.

Here is what I have

```
RepeatKey := !RepeatKey
If RepeatKey
    SetTimer, SendTheKey, 100
Else
    SetTimer, SendTheKey, Off
return

p::
Pause
Suspend
return

SendTheKey:
SendInput u
Return
```

Right now this code is toggled it just keep pressing `U` until I press the side mouse button again
Anyone know how to make it into a hold and release?

Answer (score 1):

I've always done it like this. I don't know what mouse key you're using, but for this example I'll use XButton2 which would be the browser back button on a mouse.

If you want a sleep for a 100ms, add Sleep, 100 after your SendInput command.

```
XButton2::
KeyDown := !KeyDown
If KeyDown
    SendInput {u down}
    Sleep, 100
Else
    SendInput {u up}
Return
```